# Confusion between partial and straight derivative wrt z

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, $z=x+iy$

under what conditions is $f_z=\frac{df}{dz}$?

Comment: Functions $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ only have one derivative (if they do), $\frac{df}{dz}$ or $f'(z)$. A different matter is, for example, the partial derivatives of $u,v$ as differentiable $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ functions. Maybe this is where the confusion is?